# UTF-8 in java not read propertly

Tags: java, csv

```java
final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()), "UTF-8");
                CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, format))
```

I am using commonscsv parser, but it didn't read UTF-8 file exported by Excel 
correctly. The recordMap is unsupported chars like PK     ! b�h^  �   [Content_Types].xml �(�                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 �t/"�U�ɴ)�&!3~��*�]X�K/o�y���v�5���+��zl�. Expected input was header like

[Project Key,Issue Type,Affected CI,Location,Contact,Person Contact, Phone  ,Contact Email,Start Date,End Date,Summary,Description,Reporter,Priority,   Realization Team,Affected CIs,WO Category,Country]

The file was exported as UTF-8 in tools menu by export. Its not UTF-8 BOM
file. Where could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's very hard to know what the problem is when all we're told is that "it didn't read [...] correctly". Please provide more details. What does the file contain? What are you doing with the data? What did you expect to see? What did you actually see?

Comment: `PK` looks like the file header of a (binary) Zip-file. Are you sure you are trying to read a CSV and not an `.xlsx` file? Please double-check that `file.getPath()` points to a CSV file – which can be opened with any text editor – and not something else

Comment: Yes you are right it was not exported csv, but still in new csv I have some characters that are not displayed like  **ťžč** and thats only UTF-8 file I need support multiple encodings, do I need some recogniser? Because when I am using UTF-8 and file is windows-1250 then there are more characters displayed as �

Comment: When you say "are not displayed" what exactly do you mean? Where do you display them? Does your display device/application support unicode and does it use a font which can display these characters? Are you outputting the string in the correct encoding? Is the display application aware of which encoding should be used to display?

Comment: Try to use Apache Tika for encoding estimation.